# Golang: Declare a type for a map Interface. So I can loop over that and convert to struct

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a nested map that looks like this

```
[map[datas:map[a:1 aaaa:1 blue:1 bb:1 green:1 cc:1 dd:1 red:1 ee:4 ff:2 gg:1]]]
```

how can I represent this as type?
i.e.

```
type datas map[string][]map[string]int
```

My end goal is to convert this struct like this

```
type DataStruct struct {
    Datas []struct {
        Name  string `json:"name"`
        Num int    `json:"num"`
    } `json:"datass"`
}
```

In order to do that I need to iterate through the map.
Right now I have declared it as  `type DatasType map[string]interface{}` type but it complains that I cannot range over it (variable of type interface{}).

Comment: To range over `interface{}` when the value wrapped in it is a slice/array/map/string/chan you first need to type-assert/type-switch the `interface{}` to the actual type, the result of that operation is a value of the actual type, then you can use for-range on that new value.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do, but here's what I've deduced from your question:

1. You have data in a slice/array
2. This data can be represented as a struct

This means we can safely create the following types:

```
type Data struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Num  int    `json:"num"`
}

type DataSet struct {
    Set []Data `json:"datas"`
}
```

Now assuming you're trying to (un-)marshall data that looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "foo",
            123,
        },
        {
            "bar",
            456,
        },
    ]
}
```

You can simply do this:

```
set := DataSet{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(&set, input); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for _, d := range set.Data {
    fmt.Printf("Name %s has %d num\n", d.Name, d.Num)
}
```

That should suffice. Considering your types, and your mentioning of something like `map[string][]map[string]int` (or `map[string][]map[string]interface{}`), I don't see any reason why you'd even bother using maps. The type `map[string][]map[string]any` translates to a a JSON object, where fields are arrays (or slices) of objects. Looking at the `DataSet` type, it represents an object with a field that is an array/slice of objects. That's exactly what you seem to have, and thus that's all you need.

The only time you need to faff around with hacky things like `map[string]any` is when you have no way of knowing what format and/or type the data you're handling is in. Then again, if you don't know what you're operating on, you have to ask: what can you reasonably be expected to do that is of any value?

Also worth noting: if your input JSON object(s) contain fields that your structs/types don't, `json.Unmarshal` will simply ignore those fields, so if your input looks like this:

```
{
    "random": "string value",
    "another_dataset": {}, // some object|
    "datas": [], // this is what you're after
    // ... more fields
}
```

the above `DataSet` object will still work just fine. `json.Unmarshal` only requires fields that map onto the JSON input to be of a compatible type.